# select-box on click? Hide first item when selectbox is opened, show it when closed?

Tags: jquery, select, drop-down-menu

I have this …

```
<select class="wr-dropdown">
    <option selected="" value="Navigation">Navigation</option>
    <option value="something">Something</option>
    <option value="something">Something</option>
    …
</select>
```

When clicking the dropdown I'd like to hide the first option "Navigation" … when a selection is made or the dropdown is closed I want to show it again.

How do I do that?

Comment: it defeats the purpose of the select  box but you could keep the selectd value in a hidden input and after that set the value of the select to Navigation

Comment: As a user I would find this unsettling and unexpected behavior.

Comment: @j08691 Maybe. But in my case (always depending on the interface) it makes sense and doesn't confuse.

Answer (score 2):

You can use your plain HTML for hiding the first Element of option when select is opened as:

```
<select name="list">
<option selected="selected" hidden>First Element</option>
<option>Second Element</option>
<option>Third Element</option>

</select>
```

Here is the working fiddle: https://jsfiddle.net/sujan_mhrzn/y5kxtkc6/

Answer (score 0):

```
$("select").focus(function(){  
    $(this).find("option").eq(0).remove(); 
 })
$("select").blur(function(){ 
    $(this).prepend("<option selected='selected'>Navigation</option>");
})
```

This works.

Here's the fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/klatzkaj/38tpv/

Comment: `$(this).find("option").eq(0).remove();` is what you need inside `focus`.

Comment: I'm in Chrome. The `blur()` doesn't work for me. Focus works and removes the `option` but blur doesn't add it again.

Comment: This is odd... It's working fine for me on the latest version of Chrome.

Answer (score 0):

If you do not like the way the second option jumps into select box with Andrews Method, which is a great example by the way. You could do something like this:

```
 $("select").focus(function(){  
    $(this).find("option").eq(0).html(''); 
 })
$("select").blur(function(){ 
   $(this).find("option").eq(0).html('Navigation');
})
```